# FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/missing-identifier) while sign-in using facebook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, oauth

```
try {
  const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, facebookProvider);
  const { user } = result;
} catch (error) {
  if (error.code === "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential") {
    try {
      // Check if the user has other providers linked to the same email
      const methods = await fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, error.email);
      if (methods && methods.length > 0) {
        // User has other providers linked
        // Prompt user to sign in with the existing provider to link accounts
        const signInWithExistingProvider = async (provider) => {
          try {
            await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
            // Redirect will handle linking automatically
          } catch (linkError) {
            console.error("Error linking accounts:", linkError);
          }
        };

        // Example: Prompt user to sign in with Google
        // You can add more prompts for other providers if needed
        if (methods.includes("google.com")) {
          signInWithExistingProvider(googleProvider);
        }
      }
    } catch (linkError) {
      console.error("Error fetching sign-in methods:", linkError);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Login Failed:", error);
  }
}
```

This is how I am handling the facebook login into my react app using firebase. I am using both Google login and facebook login for my react app, I am using firebase and I enabled both of these options in sign-in methods inside the authentication in firebase. What is happening is:
If a user login for the first time with his facebook, it is working fine and he logout and then tries using the Google sign-in method, it too works fine, then he logout and again tries to login using firebase, I got the error: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/account-exists-with-different-credential). For handling this, I tried the above method.
And now I am encountering with the error: Error fetching sign-in methods: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/missing-identifier). What is wrong with my code?`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

please see the [facebook-login#expandable-1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#expandable-1)

> **Handling account-exists-with-different-credential Errors**
>
> If you enabled the One account per email address setting in the
> Firebase console, when a user tries to sign in a to a provider (such
> as Facebook) with an email that already exists for another Firebase
> user's provider (such as Google), the error
> auth/account-exists-with-different-credential is thrown along with an
> AuthCredential object (Facebook access token). To complete the sign in
> to the intended provider, the user has to sign first to the existing
> provider (Google) and then link to the former AuthCredential (Facebook
> access token). Popup mode
>
> If you use signInWithPopup, you can handle
> auth/account-exists-with-different-credential errors with code like
> the following example:

```
import {
  getAuth,
  linkWithCredential,
  signInWithPopup,
  FacebookAuthProvider,
} from "firebase/auth";

try {
  // Step 1: User tries to sign in using Facebook.
  let result = await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), new FacebookAuthProvider());
} catch (error) {
  // Step 2: User's email already exists.
  if (error.code === "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential") {
    // The pending Facebook credential.
    let pendingCred = error.credential;

    // Step 3: Save the pending credential in temporary storage,

    // Step 4: Let the user know that they already have an account
    // but with a different provider, and let them choose another
    // sign-in method.
  }
}

// ...

try {
  // Step 5: Sign the user in using their chosen method.
  let result = await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), userSelectedProvider);

  // Step 6: Link to the Facebook credential.
  // TODO: implement `retrievePendingCred` for your app.
  let pendingCred = retrievePendingCred();

  if (pendingCred !== null) {
    // As you have access to the pending credential, you can directly call the
    // link method.
    let user = await linkWithCredential(result.user, pendingCred);
  }

  // Step 7: Continue to app.
} catch (error) {
  // ...
}
```